# Proof of Continuity using Alternative Characterization (Sequential Continuity)

Tags: real-analysis

Just checking if my understanding of this proof is correct.

It uses the alternative characterization of continuity, i.e. $x_n \rightarrow c$ implies $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(c).$

Question asks to show $f(x)$ is not continuos at $c=0$.

> $f(x) =$ \begin{cases} 1,  & \text{if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$} \\ 0, &
> > \text{if $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$} \end{cases}
>
> $$-$$Proof: $$f(0) = 1 \\\text{For}\ n \in \mathbb{N},\ \text{set}\
>  x_n=\frac{1}{n}\sqrt{2}. \\\text{Then for}\ n \in \mathbb{N},\ x_n \notin
>  \mathbb{Q},\ \text{so}\ f(x_n) = 0.\\ \text{We see that }x_n\rightarrow 0,\ \text{but}\
>  f(x_n)\nrightarrow f(0)\\ \text{Hence}\ f\text{ is not continuous at }0. $$

Is the reason for $f(x_n)\nrightarrow f(0)$ that $x_n=\frac{1}{n}\sqrt{2}$ is always irrational so $f(x_n)$ tends to 0, while for the function to be continuous we would require it to tend to 1?

Comment: The argument "since $x_n \to 0$ but $f_n \nrightarrow f(0)$" is enough for saying that $f$ is not continuous. (Since continuity implies that whenever $x_n \to x$ then $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ as you correctly said.) However, be sure yo are able to proof formally that $f(x_n) \nrightarrow f(0)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then sequence $x_n$ is designed so that:

$$x_n \to 0\ \text{and}\ \forall n,\ x_n \not\in\mathbb{Q}$$

This is important for at least two reasons:

**1.** 0 is the point where we want to show $f$ is discontinuous.

**2.** $f$ is defined differently for rationals and irrationals; while 0 is a rational number, every $x_n$ is by design irrational.

Hence we should expect that $\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim}f(x_n)\not=f(0).$

This turns out to be the case, since $f(0)=1$ since 0 is rational, BUT

$f(x_n)=0$ for all $n$ since $x_n \not\in \mathbb{Q}$ for all n; thus $(f(x_n))_n$ is just the constant sequence that equals 0 for all n, and therefore $\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim}f(x_n)=0\not=1=f(0)$.

If $f$ were continuous at 0, then we would have $1=0$, which is a contradiction, thus it must be discontinuous at 0.